# AJax + PHP + MYSQL Newsletter subscriber

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

Currently I am able to add a new email address to my newsletter table, however I am struggling with the AJAX part of the query, ie. the validation.

Below is my Signup.php file:

```
<?php

require_once('required/init.php');
    require_once('required/settings.php');
    require_once('required/database.php');
    require_once('required/class.phpmailer.php');
    require_once('required/globals.php');
    $email  = trim($_REQUEST["email"]);
    //  Check if subscriber exists
    $SQL= "select email from tblnewsletter where email='".$email."'";
    $result = mysql_query($SQL);
    if(!$result) {die('Problem in SQL: '.$SQL);}    //just checking if there was a problem with your query

    if (mysql_num_rows($result)==1) {   // he was subscribed already
        echo 'You are subscribed.';         // Change the message if you want.
    }
    else {          // does not exist ==> add to the table
        $SQL2= "INSERT into tblnewsletter (email) VALUES ('".$email."')";
        mysql_query($SQL2);
        echo 'Thank you for subscribing';   // Change the message if you want.
    }

?>
```

and here is my Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#nlsubmit').on('click', function() {
            signup();
            return false;
        });
    });


    function trim(str) {
        str = str.replace(/^\s*$/, '');
        return str;
    }

    function signup()
    {
        var emailentered = $("#email").val();
        var email = trim(emailentered);

        //EMAIL VALIDATION
        var goodEmail = email.match(/\b(^(\S+@).+((\.com)|(\.net)|(\.edu)|(\.mil)|(\.gov)|(\.org)|(\.info)|(\.sex)|(\.biz)|(\.aero)|(\.coop)|(\.museum)|(\.name)|(\.pro)|(\.arpa)|(\.asia)|(\.cat)|(\.int)|(\.jobs)|(\.tel)|(\.travel)|(\.xxx)|(\..{2,2}))$)\b/gi);
        var apos = email.indexOf("@");
        dotpos = email.lastIndexOf(".");
        lastpos = email.length - 1;
        var badEmail = (apos < 1 || dotpos - apos < 2 || lastpos - dotpos < 2);
        if (email == "" || !goodEmail || badEmail)
        {
            //Email address fails
            $('myResponse').style.display = 'inline';
            $('myResponse').style.color = 'red';
            alert('Please enter a valid email');
            $('email').focus();
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            email = encodeURIComponent(email);
            //Email address succeeds
            $.ajax({
                url: "signup.php?email=" + email,
                success: function(result) {
                    alert('here');
                    $('#myResponse').show();
                    $("loading").show();
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
    }
    function showResponse(req) {
        $("loading").hide();
        $("myResponse").innerHTML = req.responseText;
        $("myResponse").style.display = "inline";
        $("myResponse").style.color = "blue";
        $("submit").show();
        $("email").invoke('clear');
    }
    function showException(req) {
        $("myResponse").innerHTML = req.responseText;
        alert("An error occured while talking to the server. Please try again.");
        $("loading", "myResponse").invoke('hide');
        $("submit").show();
        $("email").invoke('clear');
    }
</script>
```

The form that is calling all this is as follows:

```
<form method="post" name="subform" id="subform" action="">
                    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="">
                    <input type="submit" id="nlsubmit" name="submit" value="Sign up">
                    <div id="myResponse" style="display:none;"></div>
                    <div id="loading" style="display:none;"><img src="/images/wait.gif" alt=""></div>

                </form>
```

Like I said the newsletter table is updated great, though I'm needing the user to be notified *on the same page* if they are already present, if the email is invalid etc.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how to validate an email address using javascript/AJAX

Comment: So, all you want to do is check if the email already exists in the database and if so, alert the user on the same page?

Comment: yes, i need some other validation aswell, as you can see from the code there are some regular expression checks for validating that the email is legit, one thing at a time though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function:

```
        $.ajax({
            url: "signup.php?email=" + email,
            success: function(result) {
                alert('here');
                $('#myResponse').show();
                $("loading").show();
                return false;
            }
        });
```

'result' refers to whatever was echoed on signup.php, so if result=="You are subscribed." that means that the email address already exists in the database, otherwise if result=="Thank you for subscribing" the email address is new to the database and the new user subscribed. So the function should look something like this:

```
       $.ajax({
            url: "signup.php?email=" + email,
            success: function(result) {
                if(result=="You are subscribed.")
                {
                  // notify user that email address already exists
                }

                alert('here');
                $('#myResponse').show();
                $("loading").show();
                return false;
            }
        });
```